# Avoid copying subdirectory contents multiple times when recursively copying files

Tags: linux, bash

The script does a simple operation of copying all files (excluding ".log" files) and all sub-directories into destination folder.  The issue I am running into is the files that reside in sub-directories are also being copied into the destination folder so the end result is that those files show up twice; in the destination folder and also the sub folders of that folder. How can this be avoided? Thanks

```
source_dir="path/to/source"
dest_dir="path/to/destination"

arg=${1}
echo $arg

if [[ ! -d $dest_dir ]]; then
    echo "creating destination directory $dest_dir"
    mkdir $dest_dir
fi  

#copy all files that don't end with .log
for resource in `find $source_dir ! -name '*.log'`; do
        echo "copying resource $resource..."
        cp -r $resource $dest_dir
done
```

Comment: Not your immediate problem, but read [BashPitfalls #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls) to understand why this code doesn't work with filenames with spaces, and [UsingFind](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) to know what to do instead. Also, run it through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix the quoting bugs identified.

Comment: ... That said, is your real question how to *exclude* a path? If so, see any of the existing Q&A entries describing use of the `-prune` action in `find`. That won't happen with your sample paths here, though, since in the code in the question the destination isn't under the source.

Comment: Or are you asking how to tell `find` not to recurse? We already have entries for that too.

Answer (score 3):

Consider replacing the `for` case with a single command:

`rsync -avz  --exclude '*.log' path/to/source/ path/to/destination/`

[`rsync`](https://www.tecmint.com/rsync-local-remote-file-synchronization-commands/amp/) does not require `rtools` to be running. and it works great locally, for a purpose just like this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think rsync has a recursion limiter, and for something like this it's probably overkill anyway.

```
(cd /path/to/source; find -maxdepth 1 ! -name \*.log | cpio -pdv /path/to/destination)
```